# ng-if not working properly on first call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The following code calls the `alert()` function on page load even though the `available` variable is null to begin with. Is this expected behavior or am I doing something wrong ?

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

  <input ng-model='available' type='text' />
  <div ng-if='available != null'>
    {{call()}}
    {{available == null}}
  </div>

</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.available = null;
    $scope.call = function() {
        alert(this.available == null);
    };
}
```

The actual usecase for me is to load an image only if certain values are present in the scope. This is a code to just mimic that functionality without involving to handle with images.

**Edit: Here is the [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/btwymkmL/1/) for the sample. You can see the alert popup on page load (or subsequent runs)**

**Edit2: Upgrading angular version from 1.0 to 1.6 helped with the example, but still facing the image issues. Updated the fiddlejs link above and the problem can be observed by looking at the devleoper tools -> network tab. There will be 2 http calls for the single image. 1. `{{available}}.jpg` and 2. `a.jpg`. But only `a.jpg` call should have happened**

Comment: @dhilt The example worked after updating angular version. But i still face the original problem with images. I have updated the fiddljs link (http://jsfiddle.net/btwymkmL/2/). If you look at the network activity in developer tools, whenever you type something in the text input (like `a`), there are two http calls made. one for `{{available}}.jpg` and another for `a.jpg`. Do you know why this happens or should I create a new question ?

Comment: I fixed that issue too, see updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your code a bit and there is no problem you described in the question.

Working DEMO: https://plnkr.co/edit/EBhB8ZxiivSWe7J1xtHK?p=info

```
<input ng-model='available' type='text' />
<div ng-if='available'>
    {{call()}}
    {{available}}
</div>

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
    $scope.available = '';
    $scope.call = function() {
        alert(!!this.available);
    };  
});
```

**UPD:** The main difference between my and your demos is the AngularJS version. I recommend you not to use v1.0.1. There were a lot of improvements and breaking changes from it to 1.6.x. And I believe, one of them is `ng-if` rendering algorithm. Use the latest stable!

**UPD2:** The next point is that before the controller finishes instantiating, the DOM still exists and your `<img>` tag with `src` attribute is being proccessed by browser. There are some ways how to avoid such an effect, the simplest one (but not the best! it's just an idea) is to control `src` attribute manually via `$scope.$watch`:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input ng-model='available' type='text' />
  <img id="myImg" />
</div>

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.available = '';
    $scope.$watch('available', function(value) {
      if(value) {
        document.getElementById('myImg').src = 
          'http://test.com/' + $scope.available + '.jpg'
      }
    });
});
```